# Cycle through an array using buttons

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

I'm fairly new to android so please forgive my ignorance or incompetence.

I am creating an app of sayings (quotes) that are stored in an array and displayed via a TextView using .setText.

I currently have it working to select and display a random saying and play its corresponding audio. I'm now looking to use a "Next" and "Back" button to cycle through the array of sayings but have been struggling to do it for a while.

I would imagine i need to find the index value of the currently displayed saying and increment or decrement it by one?

Any help would be great. Thanks.

This is what i have so far:

```
public class Sayings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

HashMap<String, Integer> sayingsResIds = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

MediaPlayer mp;

String[] sayings = {"Saying1", "Saying2", "Saying3", "Saying4", "Saying5"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sayings);

    Animation anim;

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);

    TextView sayingsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displaySayings);

    sayingsTextView.startAnimation(anim);

    Button btnRandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.random_button);
    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);

    btnRandom.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);

    sayingsResIds.put("Saying1",R.raw.saying1);
    sayingsResIds.put("Saying2",R.raw.saying2);
    sayingsResIds.put("Saying3",R.raw.saying3);
    sayingsResIds.put("Saying4",R.raw.saying4);
    sayingsResIds.put("Saying5",R.raw.saying5);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sayings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Animation anim;

    TextView sayingsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displaySayings);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in2);

    int resId = 0;

    switch  (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.random_button:

        String randomSaying = (sayings[new Random().nextInt(sayings.length)]);

        sayingsTextView.setText('"' + randomSaying + '"');

        resId = sayingsResIds.get(randomSaying);

        sayingsTextView.startAnimation(anim);
        break;

    case R.id.next_button:  
        // Click Next to find next saying in the array      
        break;

    case R.id.back_button:
        // Click Back to find the previous saying in the array
        break;
    }       

    if (mp != null) {           
    mp.release();
    }       
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mp.start();         
    }
```

Comment: Create an int class variable called something like `currentPosition` and start it at 0. If they hit next then increment (++) it and show the item at that position in the array. If they hit back then decrement (--) it and show the item at that position in the array. Just check if you are at the beginning or end index first.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I understand the pseudo for that i'm just not sure exactly how i would implement it in code.

Comment: Give it a shot and ask questions about what you come up with. The answer below is pretty much the exact same thing I said and he is spoon feeding it all to you.

Comment: I am going to and have been independently for a while. I can't currently but i will be as soon as i get the chance again. I'm looking to learn so as much as i do appreciate the exact answer its good for me to know why and understand whats going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off all you need to declare a field in a class to track current saying(quotes).

```
Integer current;
```

also you have to move following statement from onClick and declare it as a field in a class.

```
Integer resId = 0;
```

Then modify your onCreate method to have code shown below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //After buttons being declared
    current = 0;
    btnBack.setEnabled(false);
    btnNext.setEnabled(true);
    String randomSaying = (sayings[current]);
    sayingsTextView.setText('"' + randomSaying + '"');
    resId = sayingsResIds.get(randomSaying);
    sayingsTextView.startAnimation(anim); 
    //Rest of your code
}
```

Now you can modify your onClick code as follows

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //your code
    switch  (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.random_button:
            current = new Random().nextInt(sayings.length);
            String randomSaying = (sayings[current]);
            sayingsTextView.setText('"' + randomSaying + '"');
            resId = sayingsResIds.get(randomSaying);
            sayingsTextView.startAnimation(anim);
            if(current == 0){
                btnBack.setEnabled(false);
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            } else if(current == sayings.length - 1){
                btnBack.setEnabled(true);
                btnNext.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                btnBack.setEnabled(true);
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.next_button:  
            // Click Next to find next saying in the array
            if(current == 0){
                btnBack.setEnabled(true);
            }
            current++;
            String randomSaying = (sayings[current]);
            sayingsTextView.setText('"' + randomSaying + '"');
            resId = sayingsResIds.get(randomSaying);
            sayingsTextView.startAnimation(anim);  
            if(current == sayings.length - 1){
                btnNext.setEnabled(false);
            }     
            break;

        case R.id.back_button:
            // Click Next to find next saying in the array
            if(current == sayings.length - 1){
                 btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            }
            current--;
            String randomSaying = (sayings[current]);
            sayingsTextView.setText('"' + randomSaying + '"');
            resId = sayingsResIds.get(randomSaying);
            sayingsTextView.startAnimation(anim);  
            if(current == 0){
                btnBack.setEnabled(false);
            }     
            break;
    }
    // your code
}
```

Let me know if it works!

**Edit:**

Here is the concept

- For randomly determined saying

  1. if current is 0, this means we are processing first saying from array. So, we would have to disable back button because there is no saying before.
  2. if current is saying.length - 1, this means we are processing last saying from array. So, we would have to disable next button because there is no saying after.
  3. if current is greater than 0 and less than saying.length, this means we are processing saying from array which is neither first nor last. So, we would have to enable both back and next button to navigate back and forth.
- When next button is clicked

  1. if current is 0, we would be moving forward. Enable back button so that we can navigate backward.
  2. Increment current
  3. Process saying
  4. Check after increment if current is saying.length - 1, then we have reached at end of array so disable next button to restrict user from moving further.
- When back button is clicked

  1. if current is saying.length, we would be moving backward. Enable next button so that we can navigate forward.
  2. Decrement current
  3. Process saying
  4. Check after decrement if current is 0, then we have reached at beginning of array so disable back button to restrict user from moving backward.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your reply! I'm really hoping to learn from this and see where i'm going wrong to progress myself in programming so i appreciate your time.
 
I seem to be running into errors:

The first was the .setEnable on the buttons, am i right in saying that was just a typo and it should be .setEnabled?

On the resId = sayingsResIds.get(randomSaying); in the onCreate. It tells me that "resId cannot be resolved to a variable" Could that be because resId is not a global variable? 

Also all of the buttons in the switch case cannot be resolved.

Thanks again.

Comment: yes, .setEnable must be .setEnabled and to resolve error with resId, move its declaration from onClick to class level. Edited my answer to resolve these issues. Hope now it should work. Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks again for a really great answer/edit! I have done as you said but i seem to get randomSaying as a duplicate variable on the switch case for both the next and back button. Ill continue to work on it and let you know!

Comment: With some modification i was able to get the function working great! Thanks again!